# Including PHPUnit.phar in script

Tags: php, phpunit, phar

I installed the latest release of PHPUnit using the phar according to the documentation.  I have some scripts to compile a code coverage report using the `PHP_CodeCoverage` object.  With the update, when I try to include `phpunit.phar` phpunit is actually run.  The script outputs the list of options for running PHPUnit and then exits.

How can I include the file so that I have the PHPUnit objects available in my script?

The line that I tried was

```
require '/usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit creates and registers an autoload function for including its files in `phpunit.phar`.  I was able to use the `PHPUnit` classes in my script by extracting this function.

The code is available on [Github](https://gist.github.com/EpeeCheeze/32a83b173365b16b9c0f)

Basically, all the class paths are mapped and then included via `require phar:///user/local/bin/phpunit.phar/<class path>`